# DD tag HTML problem

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c

Why effect of DD tag differs in this pages?

[removed]

[removed]

First example also doesn't work in Chrome. Firefox is ok.

I want in node/159 same as in test.htm.

**UPDATED:** The links removed.

Comment: You have no `<dt>` or `<dl>` elements. Whatever you are using the `<dd>` element for, it is being used completely incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to indent the first line of each paragraph then:

- Don't use a `<dd>` element
- Do use a  `<p>` element
- Do use the CSS [text-indent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#indentation-prop) property

Comment: +1. Plus remove the top and bottom `margin`​s if necessary. There are also other validation errors on the page which could confuse browsers; validation is the first step to ensuring consistent treatment.